# How to Protect Against Symbol Redefinition

Tags: c, eclipse, typedef, redefinition, codewarrior

My project incorporates a stack, which has a number of user-defined types (`typedef`).  The problem is that many of these type definitions conflict with our in-house type definitions.  That is, the same symbol name is being used.  Is there any way to protect against this?

The root of the problem is that to use the stack in our application, or wrapper code, as the case may be, a certain header file must be included.  This stack header file in turn includes the stack provider's types definition file.  That's the problem.  They should have included their type definition file via a non-public include path, but they didn't.  Now, there are all sorts of user-defined type conflicts for very common names, such as `BYTE`, `WORD`, `DWORD`, and so forth.

Comment: Can you put a wrapper around the stack?

Comment: @WilliamMorris That's what I'm trying to do, which is why these differences need to be resolved.

Comment: The root of the problem is: why are you getting naming conflicts in the first place? Is the stack not using any proper naming convention, or is it the application, or both? Are there conflicts with the standard C library (aka bugs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I've come up with a reasonable workaround, for the time being, but as Lundin stated, a formal coding standard is needed for a long-term solution.

Basically what I did was to move the inclusion of the required stack header file to before the inclusion of our in-house type definitions file.  Then, between those two includes I added a compiler macro to set a defined constant dependent on whether the stack's header file single-include protection definition has been defined.  Then, I used that conditional defined constant as a conditional compile option in our in-house type definition file to prevent the conflicting data-types from being re-defined.  It's a little sloppy, but progress can only be made in incremental steps.

Comment: That makes your project subordinate to the stack, which sounds odd. If the stack changes its definitions in an incompatible way, you may have to change your project's type definitions file (quite an important file I would guess) rather than just changing the wrapper file that I suggested.  Most likely, such changes will not occur so the problem will not arise, but I'd prefer the dependency the other way around :-)

Comment: Note that your solution also means that some of your source files and any headers they include will be compiled with type definitions that come from the project and others, those that use the stack, (and any headers they include) will be compiled with type definitions that originate in the stack. This might lead to subtle errors that are hard to find...

Comment: @WilliamMorris Thanks, but that is the purpose of the wrapper code, at least insofar as my project is concerned.  Indeed, the stack may change in later versions, and the wrapper code would need to be modified accordingly.  However, that is all that would need to change.  I have my wrapper code setup with public and private include files, so that other projects utilizing the generated library will not have to deal with any of this mess.

Answer (score 1):

Since you probably can't easily change the program stack you are using, you will have to start with your own code.

The first thing to do is (obviously) to limit the number of names in the global namespace, as far as possible. Don't use global variables, just use static ones, as an example.

The next step is to adopt a naming convention for your code modules. Suppose you have an "input module" in the project. You could then for example prefix all functions in the input module "inp".

```
void inp_init (void); 
void inp_get  (int input);

#define INP_SOMECONSTANT 4

typedef enum
{
  INP_THIS,
  INP_THAT,
} inp_something_t;
```

And so on. Whenever these items are used elsewhere in the code, they will not only have a unique identifier, it will also be obvious to the reader which module they belong to, and therefore what purpose they have. So while fixing the namespace conflicts, you gain readability at the same time.

Something like the above could be the first steps to implementing a formal coding standard, something you need to do sooner or later anyway as a professional programmer.

Comment: I don't think this addresses the problem. As I understand it, the two sides of the system define types with the same names. This means that the input stack cannot include the system headers and the system cannot include the stack headers because of redefinition errors. Even if they define the types the same, including opposing headers will not compile.

Comment: @WilliamMorris The stack will not include the rest of the application, that doesn't make sense. This is likely some communication protocol stack, TCP/IP, CANopen, Ethernet, whatever. It will be on the lower hardware layers of the program, while the caller is the actual application. The responsibility to keep naming conflicts away is then in the caller. Anyway, this isn't obvious with the limited information given in the question.

Comment: No I know the stack wont include the app headers. But imagine you want to write a wrapper to join the two. You'd like to include the stack headers, convert their functions to your types and then export the converted functions. But you can't because when you try to include your own headers into the wrapper as well as the stack's headers, they conflict.

Comment: @Lundin Thank you for the thoughtful suggestions.  The naming convention you implemented is very similar to what I implement on the modules I code.  I was recently hired by a very small company as their first engineer dedicated 100% to firmware development.  The situation being what it is, much of their existing code base ... needs attention.

Comment: @JimFell I'm very familiar with that situation myself :) To make a formal coding standard alone in a small company, is lots of work, but it is worth it in the end. I'd strongly recommend using [MISRA-C](http://www.misra-c.com/Activities/MISRAC/tabid/160/Default.aspx) as a base, pick what you like from it, and then as the next step, decide on code formatting and naming rules.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you define a wrapping header that redefines all of the functions and structures exported by the stack in terms of your own types. This header is then included in your system files but not in the stack files (where it would conflict).  You can then compile and link but there is a weak point at the interface.  If you select your types correctly in your redefinitions, it should work correctly, leaving **only** an maintenance problem on each update from the stack supplier...